# Remove edit button on ThumbnailViewController PDFTron

Tags: ios, ipad, pdftron

I have a requirement wherein I do not need the Edit/ Delete button that appears in ThumbnailViewController for PDFTron Library iOS. I have seen that the control for this is available in ThumbnailsViewController.m. But I am using dynamic framework and therefore I do not have access to this file. How can I remove this feature? [image: Please see attached image for reference]

Now I am able to generate the updated Tools framework but when I replace it in the project, I am encountering the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Tools.framework/Tools
  Referenced from: /Users/sus/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0B6B340D-AE6A-4B91-B8C4-294FDC50D204/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D568E9C5-1D13-475B-BB3A-C892AE0D29FA/Complete Reader.app/Complete Reader
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/sus/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0B6B340D-AE6A-4B91-B8C4-294FDC50D204/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D568E9C5-1D13-475B-BB3A-C892AE0D29FA/Complete Reader.app/Frameworks/Tools.framework/Tools: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

This is happening both on the sample as well as my app.This happens when I try to build for Generic iOS device. It works fine when I build for any simulator.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I believe the issue with the "Library not loaded" error was sorted via email, when you updated to the latest version of PDFNet iOS SDK. It would be great to make this question answered. Either the first question, about the edit button, which I answered below, or the second one, in which case you should answer your own question.

Comment: Actually I am still struggling with creating a universal Tools framework after making changes to Tools source code. I have tried some Run scripts to create a universal framework but I am unable to create one.

Comment: Could you update your question, clearly showing what you tried, and the latest error messages you got.

Answer (score 0):

To remove these options you need to modify the ThumbnailViewController.m file.

> But I am using dynamic framework and therefore I do not have access to
>   this file.

That should not be an issue. You should be able to modify and build the Tools framework in XCode. If you are still stuck, please update your question on what you mean exactly by "I do not have access to this file."

Comment: I have tried doing that. But when I build the Tools framework in Xcode I am unable to get the path where the updated Tools framework is found.